# How do cron jobs work in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron

My model:

```
class Uzer < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :uzer
  set_table_name 'managers'

  def self.synchronize_emails
    get_emails_from_uzer    = Uzer.find(:all)   
    get_emails_from_flower  = Respondent.find(:all)

      get_emails_from_uzer.each do |e|
        Respondent.create(:email => e.email, :user_id => 6, :respondent_group_id => e.organisational_id)
      end
  end

end
```

Everything is perfect, BUT...

I want to execute `def self.synchronize_emails` every hour to get emails from another database and insert into my database.

I tried to use this -> https://github.com/javan/whenever

I installed the gem, created config/schedule.rb and wrote:

```
every 2.minutes do
  runner "Mossad.synchronize_emails"
end
```

*(just for test to see it works or not)*

However, nothing happens. Any ideas / suggestions? I WANT cron!:(

Thank you!

---

**UPDATE:**

I wrote in console: `whenever --update-crontab store`

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: store
0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/ee-vzaharov/Projects/AptanaRadRails/survey && script/runner -e production '\''Mossad.synchronize_emails'\'''

# End Whenever generated tasks for: store
~                                                                                                                            
~                                                                                                                            
~                                                                                                                            
~                                                                                                                            
~                                                                                                                            
~                                                                                                                            
~                                                                                                                            
~                                                                                                                            
~                                                                                                                            
~                                                                                                                            
~                                                                                                                            
~                                                                                                                            
~                                                                                                                            
~                                                                                                                            
~                                                                                                                            
~                                                                                                                            
~                                                                                                                            
~                                                                                                                            
~                                                                                                                            
~                                                                                                                            
~                                                                                                                            
~                                                                                                                            
~                                                                                                                            
Type  :quit<Enter>  to exit Vim
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with `crontab -e` if whenever created entries in your crontab. If not, run the commands:

```
cd /path/to/file
whenever --update-crontab store
```

And the plugin will update the crontab (check it again with `crontab -e`)

Comment: thank you, i have been checked and I updated what i have done. What now i did wrong? nothing happens again!

Comment: Run at command line the cron's command. Probably the script raises an error :S. For example it is executed on production environment. Have you got the production database with data?

Answer (score 2):

With `cron` you can schedule the following `cd /path/to/web/app && /path/to/rake -s name_of_task` to be run whenever you want. I have not used the mentioned gem, `cron` seems just fine.

Use `crontab -e` to edit the crontab of a current user. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) has a nice article on how to use it, if you need.

Comment: dont undertand where i should write it!

Comment: Call `crontab -e` from the command line. It will open an editor in which you can edit the scheduled operations. Write a line according to the syntax of cron, as detailed in the wiki article I linked. When you exit the editor, cron should acknowledge the changes and print a message about it.